# TWRP Stuck on Boot Screen Nexus 7

Tags: rooting

I have installed TWRP onto my Nexus 7 (2012) and have gone into Recovery Mode. This has led me to be stuck on the Google Boot Screen. What do I do to fix this? I have been using this guide: http://itsfoss.com/root-nexus-7-2013-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow a guide for the **2012** Nexus 7 instead, which the model is called **Nakasi (Grouper/WiFi, Tilapia/3G-WiFi)**. You're using the wrong image, **2013** Nexus 7, which the model is called **Razor (Flo/WiFi, Debian/3G-WiFi)**, for your device. That's why its not wanting to get past the boot screen. Download from the link below or go to XDA Forum.

[Here is the link to the factory images for Nexus devices](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images)

Scroll down to the Nexus 7 2012 and select which model you have.

[Here is a link for Universal Nexus Linux Toolkit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1848036)

You can get the image from inside the program. *This will run on Linux and Mac OSX*. This will take care of all the commands.

---

**Edit**
I did see at the bottom of the guide you used that it states for the 2012 model to use a earlier (older) version of TWRP, but it doesn't show anywhere a link to any 2012 images - just to the 2013 image.